# Trouble ensuring base URL is passed in jest consumer pact requests

Tags: jestjs, fetch-api, pact

I have a service consumer pact test that I am writing, and it seems that when an API call is made it will remove the base url from the request path.

For context, here is the test I am attempting to run.

```
import { pactWith } from 'jest-pact';
import { Matchers } from '@pact-foundation/pact';
import { ProviderApi } from 'provider-app-api';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

globalThis.fetch = fetch;
pactWith(
  { consumer: 'ConsumerApp', provider: 'ProviderApp', port: 1234 },
  (provider) => {
    let providerApi;
    beforeEach(() => {
      providerApi = new ProviderApi(
        provider.mockService.baseUrl,
        'access_token'
      );
    });
    describe('ProviderApp API', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        return provider.addInteraction({
          state: 'A get request to /segments/{segment_code}/makes',
          uponReceiving: 'Some makes exist with segment code vehicles',
          withRequest: {
            method: 'GET',
            path: `${provider.mockService.baseUrl}/segments/vehicles/makes`,
            headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer access_token' },
          },
          willRespondWith: {
            status: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8' },
            body: Matchers.like({
              id: 1,
              code: 'TOYO',
              description: 'Toyota',
              start_year: 2011,
              end_year: 2021,
              segment_code: 'vehicles',
            }),
          },
        });
      });

      it('returns a successful body', () => {
        return vehiclelinkApi.fetchMakes('vehicles').then((response) => {
          // assertions to go here
          expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        });
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Upon running the test, I get this output:

```
$ yarn run test:consumer_pact
  console.error
    

      at node_modules/@pact-foundation/src/httpPact.ts:121:17

  console.error
    Pact verification failed!

      at node_modules/@pact-foundation/src/httpPact.ts:122:17

  console.error
    Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.
    
    Missing requests:
        GET http://127.0.0.1:1234/segments/vehicles/makes
    
    Unexpected requests:
        GET /segments/vehicles/makes

    
    See /home/stefan/project/pact/logs/ConsumerApp-ProviderApp-mockserver-interaction-port-1234.log for details.
```

It would seem that it's remving the base URL from the fetch call, so the pact server never receives the request, which makes sense. How do I force this to be appended in the call when I use the ProviderAPI? I've ensured that I'm passing `provider.mockService.baseUrl` in the request, and I've ensured that the value is `localhost:1234`. Is this an issue that would need to be resolved inside of the ProviderApi package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That baseUrl shouldn't be in the `path` property, which should just take the path, not the full URI

I.e. it should just be this

```
path: "/segments/vehicles/makes",
```

Comment: Gah, so simple. Thank you for your help.